# Ordered function defenitions | Benefits

Tags: javascript

Jslint will call out errors if functions are defined out of order.

Obviously jslint is strict, but I wonder if there are any benefits to putting functions in order.

By that I mean defining them before they are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define function before calling it, the code can be handled by one pass compiler, otherwise, you need a multi-pass compiler (which is slower in general).

Maybe there are some one pass JavaScript compilers out there (however, I don't know any).

I always think JSLint shows that error because it wants to make sure your code can run in a one pass compiler successfully

Comment: interesting...so you are not certain if js has one pass compilation though?

Comment: Right, I haven't done research on that topic. But I'm not surprised at all if there are those compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Function definitions (and `var` statements) are hoisted to the top of their closure. In other words, code is executing in an order that is not the same as what you wrote.

Now, there is nothing more "wrong" about it than leaving off the `;` at the end of lines, but jsLint is designed to test the **human**-readability of the code. Jumping around isn't human-readable, so it's considered invalid.

Comment: Readability to me means...grouping function definitions together in logical groups., and this does not always correlate to them being defined before they are called.

Comment: hoisting does not mean that something like `var myfunc = function() {}` is at the top. It will just move the `var myfunc` to the top. So if you try to call it before it is assigned, it will still fail.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

This will succeed:

```
var x = y();

function y() { return 9; }
```

But this will fail:

```
var x = y();

var y = function() { return 9; };
```

When the first script is interpreted it will see `function y` and will make that function available throughout its scope (being the global scope in that example).

Whereas with the second example a function is assigned to `y`. And just like any other variable the order matters.